# How to convert multiple XCF files to PNG?

Tags: bash, images, gimp, png

I have a folder with a lot of `xcf` files which I want all to be converted to `png` files, at best via a one-liner from bash.

How can I achieve such a task?

Comment: With [xcf2png](http://henning.makholm.net/software)...

Comment: @jasonwryan Thanks, worked like a charm.

Comment: You may want to give a try to `convert` tool from ImageMagick. Supports a lot of formats and operations, might be useful in future.

Comment: any of the `xcf2png` or ImageMagick answers won't work with the current XCF version (v. 12). This answer is currently (2022-07) effective: [image manipulation - How to convert XCF to PNG using GIMP from the command-line? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794640/how-to-convert-xcf-to-png-using-gimp-from-the-command-line/5846727#5846727)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One-liner from bash:

`for i in *.xcf; do xcf2png -f $i -o $i.png; done`

Comment: does not work for xcf created by new gimp2, this tool is too old

Answer (score 6):

You can use GIMP Image editor and use *Export to* tool. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> as shortcut.
Or you could use `convert` from `imagemagick`:

```
convert filename.xcf filename.png
```

You could also use  `xcftools` (sudo apt-get install xcftools), which has a utility called `xcf2png` that does this job perfectly.

```
xcf2png image.xcf -o image.png
```

Answer (score 2):

same of @k0pernikus, but remove `xcf` extension from output filename

`for i in *.xcf; do xcf2png -f $i -o "${i%.*}.png"; done`

Answer (score 1):

My one-liner using convert from imagemagik:

```
for i in Amplicon*.xcf; do convert $i ${i/xcf/png}; done
```

I had to keep my 'Amplicon' name because otherwise, it finds hidden xcf files in the directory and exports all the layers as individual PNGs haha. But it works!
And the variant not using a loop (and could be parallelized)

```
find . -name "Amplicon*xcf" | xargs -I {} convert {} {}.png
```

But... I coudn't remove the '.xcf" from the filename. Still works!

Answer (score 1):

Based on J. Auger's solution:

```
find . -name "Amplicon*xcf" | parallel convert {} {.}.png
```